# How to validate a ngModel with a list value on angular form validation?

Tags: angular

I'm need validate a list on angular. This validation will make sure that the list is not null and have at least one value.

Actually i'm using required on the component that have the list and this work well to   ensure that the list is not null, but now i need show a error when the list is empty.

I thought of one directive like the example on angular guide, but i have no ideia how to do this with a ngModel that has a list value.

Angular version: 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer your question if you don't provide a code example of what you try to achieven and show us what you have tried so far. If I understand you correctly you want to show/hide an component/html element depending on the size of a list or if it null. You can do this with an easy *ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="myList.size() > 0">
   Only shows when your List is not null and has 
   elements inside
</div>
```